# JS - call a parent function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this JS code structure and I' wondering how to call the function move() from inside the function load:

JS

```
function Start(data) {

    this.move= function() {
      ....
    };

    function load(){
       // call move
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function Start(data) {
    this.move = function() {
       ....
    };

    function load(obj) {
      obj.move();
    }

    load(this);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function Start(data) {
    var _this = this;

    this.move = function() {
      console.log('mode');
    }

    function load() {
       _this.move();
    }

    // load();
}

Start();
new Start();
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `Start()` has to be instantiated as an object. So you would use:

```
function Start(data) {

  this.move = function() {
  ....
  };

  this.load = function(){
   // call move
    this.move();
  }
}

var s = new Start(foobar);
s.load();
```

Comment: `load` is private, `this` within it would be `window`

Answer (score 1):

This is a javascript closure. I've found  [this](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closures.shtml)   site to be helpful.

```
 var move = function () {
            alert("move");
        };

        load();
        function load() {
            move();
        }
```

This code will `alert Move` only once.

Answer (score 1):

By using closures, that can be acheived by stroing the parent reference;

```
function Start(data) {
    var me = this;

    this.move= function() {
      ....
    };

    function load(){
       me.move();// call move
    }

}
```

Good Luck.